# how to handle Geokit::Geocoders::GeocodeError in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, geocode, geokit

Hi, I am using Geokit plugin in Ruby on Rails 3, it works fine for me. But when I give origin value not in a proper way it throws **Geokit::Geocoders::GeocodeError**

Here is my code:

```
@listing = Listing.geo_scope(:origin=>"sdfaasssssssdfdfsdfdfdfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf")
```

Error:

```
Geokit::Geocoders::GeocodeError: Geokit::Geocoders::GeocodeError
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/geokit-1.5.0/lib/geokit/mappable.rb:282:in `normalize'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/geokit-rails3-0.1.2/lib/geokit-rails3/acts_as_mappable.rb:229:in `normalize_point_to_lat_lng'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/geokit-rails3-0.1.2/lib/geokit-rails3/acts_as_mappable.rb:189:in `extract_origin_from_options'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/geokit-rails3-0.1.2/lib/geokit-rails3/acts_as_mappable.rb:111:in `geo_scope'
from (irb):3
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from D:/ariv/projects/RubyMine/rentstore/script/rails:6:in `require'
from D:/ariv/projects/RubyMine/rentstore/script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>
```

How to handle this error?

Thanks,

L. Arivarasan

Comment: You can rescue it right?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what you really mean, but maybe you want something like this

```
    begin
        @listing = Listing.geo_scope(:origin=>"sdfaasssssssdfdfsdfdfdfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf")
    rescue Geokit::Geocoders::GeocodeError
        # handle the error here :-)
    end
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct we have to handle it through try catch block. Thanks!